# stopping an linux aws instance from linux command line

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there a way to stop and AWS ec2 instance from the VM itself? 
If i start a ec2 linux based instance, is there a way for me to stop that instance by giving some linux command like "shutdown now"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Terminate Amazon EC2 instance using shutdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305085/terminate-amazon-ec2-instance-using-shutdown)

Answer (score 21):

It's working with

`shutdown -h now`

or

`shutdown -h +10`

If you don't use "-h" parameter to halt, the instance will keep on running state.

Comment: `sudo shutdown -h now` did it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, with a couple of caveats.

1. If you are using an instance store backed instance, your only option will be to terminate. Without EBS volumes, the instance cannot exist in a stopped state.
2. There is also a flag that can be set on the instance as to how instance initiated shutdown is handled. This can be stop or terminate. If you want to stop your instance, make sure that this flag is configured correctly.

Other than that, you would use the normal Linux shutdown commands. `shutdown now`

Comment: Just a warning: It's a good idea to enable "Termination Protection" for your  EC2 instance.

Comment: I ran `sudo shutdown now` from the running instance which stopped, but the EC2 console still showed it as running (with problems)

Comment: krock:  that's expected; you probably want `shutdown -h now` to "power off" the virtual instance (or any of its synonyms, see `shutdown --help`).  This surprises a lot of people who are accustomed to PCs, but imagine the command-line equivalent of a BIOS menu.  Shutting down an OS would leave you at that "BIOS menu" command prompt, and that's what the shutdown command is doing.

Answer (score 4):

Try these commands.

```
1. sudo poweroff
2. sudo shutdown -h now
```

[image]